# How can i list all the files in a folder with a specific name in matlab?

Tags: string, matlab, loops, dir, xlsread

I have been making a loop that assign Mx names for 121 different files in a folder.

```
    allFiles = dir( '*.xls''String' );
allNames = { allFiles.name };

for ii = 1:length(allNames) M(ii) = xlsread(allFiles(1i)); 
end
```

Trouble is that there is no errormessage, but it isn't assigning any names for the values/files i want it to.

```
listing = dir('*.xls');

disp(listing);
```

When i make a simple dir() it tells me

```
 121x1 struct array with fields:
    name
    date
    bytes
    isdir
    datenum
```

But i have to make it a String in order for xlsread() to work.

What i want it to is to make a name for each file so i can handle them in matlab, (ie. addtion of two matrices).

What can be wrong?

Comment: What is the error message? How many files really have the extension `.xls'String`? Anyway, parentheses vs. brackets: `allfiles(ii)` returns that cell (as a 1x1 cell array) - `allfiles{ii}` returns the _contents_ of that cell.

Comment: Nothing really, there is no errormessage. Those object i had from 1-24 was from another script in the editor. The workspace doesn't get any Mx objects. Doing {} instead of () doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Does your actual code have this typo in it: `allFiles(1i)` instead of `allfiles(ii)`?

Comment: originally it had just one (i) but matlab recommended to make it {1i} for optimizing speed was the argument. Making it {ii} doesn't make any difference either.

Comment: Matlab suggested `ii` NOT `1i`. `1i` appears to be a typo on your part. We can't solve your problem with the information you've given us, but you should be able to interact with the command line a little bit and figure out which of the statements is not doing what you want it to.

Comment: `1i` would generate an error if the loop ever ran. The loop doesn't run because `length(allnames)` is zero. `length(allnames)` is zero because whilst you have 121 files with the extension `.xls`, you have none with the extension `.xls'String`. Oh look, _I pointed that out already_...

Comment: How could i then convert the allFiles to be a string? by the Num2String command?

`Error using xlsread (line 122)
Filename must be a string.`

Comment: `xlsread` takes a filename, not a structure. Either use `allnames{ii}` or scrap `allnames` entirely and just use `allfiles(ii).name`

Comment: I've added num2str(), but it repeats `Undefined function 'fix' for input arguments of type 'struct'.

Error in num2str (line 65)
        if ~isempty(x) && isequalwithequalnans(x, fix(x))

Error in MatrixscRipt (line 6)
allFiles = num2str(allFiles1);`

to me. (there are only 9 lines in the script and it says there is an error in line 65.)

Comment: allNames is just important because it contains how many files there are as in quantity.

Comment: "How could i then convert the allFiles to be a string?" You can use `{}` curly brackets instead of `()` parentheses, as @Notlikethat noted. For instance, take the `'String'` out of the `dir` command, then try `xlsread(allNames{ii});` - see what you get. If you want to try just one file for testing, you can type on the command line `xlsread(allNames{0})` or `xlsread(allFiles(0).name)`. If you get some error about strings, switch whether you use `{}` or `()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is basically just typos and confusion of variables:

```
allFiles = dir('*.xls'); % correct file extension

for ii = 1:size(allFiles, 1) % allFiles has one row per file, so loop over those
    M{ii} = xlsread(allFiles(ii).name); % store matrix in cell array
end
```

Note that `M` is now a cell array, because you can't store multiple matrices in a matrix or vector.

Comment: Confirmed. M1-M121 now gives me a matrix as expected.